# Need to add a new option button when the 'add heading' clicked and it should get updated in the existing options

Tags: javascript

i need to add a new option button when the 'add heading' clicked and it should get updated in the existing options. when i look for options on the select, it should be there, How i can achieve this in javascript. Any Idea?

New update: Hi, Here i've changed my code, now, when i press the 'Add chapter' button, then, it should add the user entered chapter head to both chapter's select, there are two chapter places, so, whenever i click the 'add chapter' button, then the entered value should be updated in two places[both places]. But, When i press the add chapter' button, after entering the value on the prompt box, it showing error. I want to make this happen. Any idea? pls

```
    <html>
    <head><title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
<div id="mainsec1" style="border: 1pt solid; width: 40%;padding: 10pt">
<div id="sec1">
<span class="head1">Chapter</span>&#x00A0;&#x2009;<select name="startype" id="starselect">
<option selected="selected"> </option>
<option value="Aquila">Aquila</option>
<option value="Centaurus">Centaurus</option>
<option value="Canis Major">Canis Major</option>
</select> <span class="head1"><input type="button" class="buttonit" value="Delete" onclick="Delerow();"/></span>
</div>
<div id="sec2">
<span class="head1">Heading</span>&#x00A0;<select name="startypeHead" id="starheading">
<option selected="selected"> </option>
<option value="Aquila">Aquila Heading</option>
<option value="Centaurus">Centaurus Heading</option>
<option value="Canis Major">Canis Major Heading</option>
</select> <span class="head1"><input type="button" class="buttonit" value="Delete" onclick="Delerowsub();"/></span>
</div>
<input type="button" class="buttonit" value="Add Heading" onclick="AddHead();"/></div>
<div id="mainsec2" style="margin-top: 10pt;border: 1pt solid; width: 40%;padding: 10pt">
<div id="sec3">
<span class="head1">Chapter</span>&#x00A0;<select name="startypechap" id="starselectchap">
<option selected="selected"> </option>
<option value="Aquila">Aquila Chapter</option>
<option value="Centaurus">Centaurus Chapter</option>
<option value="Canis Major">Canis Major  Chapter</option>
</select> <span class="head1"><input type="button" class="buttonit" value="Delete" onclick="Delerow();"/></span>
</div>
</div><input type="button" class="buttonitonsub" value="Add Chapter" onclick="AddChap();"/>
</form>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    var glovar;
    document.getElementById('starselect').onchange = function(){
    var list = document.forms[0].startype;
    glovar = list.selectedIndex;
    //alert(list.selectedIndex);
    var sublist = document.forms[0].startypeHead;
    sublist.selectedIndex = glovar;
    }
    function AddHead(){
    var inpVal=prompt("Input your Heading", "Heading");
    var opele =document.createElement("option");
    opele.setAttribute("value",inpVal);
    var texEle = document.createTextNode(inpVal);
    opele.appendChild(texEle);
    //document.body.appendChild(opele);
    }

function AddChap(){
  var inpVal=prompt("Input your Chapter", "Chapter");
  var select = document.getElementById("starselectchap"); 
  var select1 = document.getElementById("starselect");
  var opele =document.createElement("option");
  opele.value = inpVal;
  opele.text = inpVal;
  select.add(opele);
//  alert(select1.add(opele));
}
    </SCRIPT>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `AddHead()` function to this

```
function AddHead(){
    var inpVal = prompt("Input your Heading", "Heading");
    var select = document.getElementById("starheading"); 
    var opele = document.createElement("option");
    opele.value = inpVal;
    opele.text = inpVal;
    select.add(opele);
}
```

Check the working [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/yucegepi/1/edit?html,js,output)